# How to add nginclude to DOM via javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am looking to include a div with ng-include="'abc.html'" into an HTML from a javascript. Please let me know how to add this as am facing issues to get the ng-include value within " ' ' ".

Comment: What is the goal of doing this?

Comment: try to escape the single quotes. i.e., instead of "''" use this "\'\'"

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of conditionally including partials in angular. Here are a few methods.

1. Use ng-show / ng-hide to show or hide the element that is included using ng-include. This only achieves a show or hide and doesnt take it out of the DOM.
2. Put an ng-switch on top of the ng-include div. Make changes to the variable that the switch observes and toggle the inclusion or non-inclusion using the ng-switch value.
3. ng-include itself takes a variable. If you dont set that variable or set it to null, then it will not show anything until you change the value of the variable to point to your partial location.